# Is there any way to stop jQuery.map at first match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects where I search by id, I want stop jQuery.map after the first match, It is a waste of time continue searching after has found out the desire it value.

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{id:1, val: ''},{id:2, val: ''}];
var index = $.map(arrayOfObjects, function (obj, index) {
    if (obj.id === id) {
        return index;
    }
});
```

I want that the return aslo stop the map excecution.

Is there any way to achieve it with $.map() or other way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using a `break;` statement?

Comment: If the JQuery `.map()` actually calls the native `Array.prototype.map()`, then the only way it is place the code in a `try` and throw an exception, which you then recover from in the `catch`. That approach is, however, not advised for performance reasons.

Comment: @ScottMarcus [`jQuery.map()`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=$.map) does not call `Array.prototype.map()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain javascript method `findIndex()` for this.

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{id:1, val: ''},{id:2, val: ''}];
var index = arrayOfObjects.findIndex(obj => obj.id == 2);
console.log(index)
```

Comment: But, you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it with $.map() **or other way to do it?**

Comment: `Is there any way to stop jQuery.map at first match`

Comment: Is it possible to include anonymous function inside findIndex?

Comment: Yes that is just arrow function, here is regular function https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2398/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to stop `$.map()` callback function from iterating next element of array.

You can alternatively use `$.each()` and return `false`

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  val: ''
}, {
  id: 2,
  val: ''
}];
var index = [];
var id = 1;
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(i);
  if (obj.id === id) {
    // `.push()` the object `obj` or current index `i` of iteration here
    index.push(i);
    return false
  }    
});
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```